# Add displacement data to mesh points

Tags: python, vtk, paraview, pyvista

Suppose I have a mesh with Tet4 elements. The mesh has a total of 1695 nodes and 7726 elements. Now I can use pyvista to create the undeformed mesh like this:

```
points = Node_Data[:,1:4]
cells = EL_Data[:, 1:5]
cells= np.insert(cells, 0, 4, axis = 1)
celltypes = np.empty(7726, dtype=np.float32)
celltypes[:] = vtk.VTK_TETRA
grid = pv.UnstructuredGrid(cells, celltypes, points)
mesh = grid
mesh.n_cells
mesh.n_points
mesh.bounds
mesh.save("test1234.vtk")
```

My question is how do I add in displacement data into this mesh? So that in paraview, it will look like this:

[image: final data]

My current data looks like this:

[image: current data]

Or is there any other method to work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ParaView, but it looks like you want to add vector-valued point data to your mesh. Many of PyVista's examples implicitly do that, but this is also mentioned in [the Basic API Usage](https://docs.pyvista.org/user-guide/simple.html#accessing-the-wrapped-data-object) page of the documentation.

Assuming you have an array called `displacements` with shape `(mesh.n_points, 3)` (i.e. one 3-dimensional vector for each point in the mesh) where the vectors are in the same order as the mesh points, you just have to do

```py
mesh.point_data['U'] = displacements
mesh.active_vectors_name = 'U'  # make these active vectors
```

This will define this array to be associated with your points, with a label of `'U'`. For cell data you would need `mesh.cell_data[...] = ...`, but obviously the shape of the corresponding data array would have to be `(mesh.n_cells, 3)` (for vector-valued data).

Here's a simple example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pyvista as pv
>>> mesh = pv.Box()  # no arrays here
>>> mesh.point_data['U'] = np.arange(mesh.n_points * 3).reshape(-1, 3)
>>> mesh.active_vectors_name = 'U'
>>> mesh.point_data
pyvista DataSetAttributes
Association     : POINT
Active Scalars  : U
Active Vectors  : U
Active Texture  : None
Active Normals  : None
Contains arrays :
    U                       int64    (8, 3)               VECTORS
```

You can see in the printout that the `point_data` contains a dataset with label `'U'`, int dtype and shape `(8, 3)`, set as active vectors. Various filters either use active vectors or accept an explicit label to use as vectors (i.e. `'U'` in this case).

Comment: Hi Andras, thank you for your answer. I wrote a vtk file out and post it above. but, I will try your answer as well. much appreciated. :)

Comment: @ryty if it works for you you can also print the vtk file with pyvista. But I assume your answer tries to avoid pyvista altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Updates:
I managed to write a vtk file to show vector values.

```
Outputfile = open('test.vtk','w')
Outputfile.write('# vtk DataFile Version 3.8\n')
Outputfile.write('test.vtk\n')
Outputfile.write('ASCII\n')
Outputfile.write('DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID\n')
Outputfile.write('POINTS ' + str(len(nodes)) + ' float\n')
for i in range(0,len(nodes)):
    Outputfile.write(str(x[i] + curr_U[idxnodes[i] * 3 + 0]) +' '\
                     + str(y[i] + curr_U[idxnodes[i] * 3 + 1])+ ' '\
                     +str(z[i] + curr_U[idxnodes[i] * 3 + 2])+'\n' )
Outputfile.write('CELLS ' + str(len(tets)) +' '+str((len(tets) * 5))+'\n')
for i in range(0,len(tets)):
    Outputfile.write('4 ' + str(n_idx[i][0]) +' '\
                     + str(n_idx[i][1])+' '+ str(n_idx[i][2])+' '+ str(n_idx[i][3])+ '\n' )   
Outputfile.write('CELL_TYPES ' + str(len(tets)) +' \n')
for i in range(0,len(tets)):
    Outputfile.write('10'+'\n' )
Outputfile.write('POINT_DATA ' + str(len(nodes)) +' \n')
Outputfile.write('VECTORS ' + 'test.vtk ' +' float\n')
for i in range(0,len(nodes)):
    Outputfile.write(str(curr_U[m_idxnodes[i] * 3 + 0]) +' '\
                     + str(curr_U[m_idxnodes[i] * 3 + 1])+ ' '\
                     +str(curr_U[m_idxnodes[i] * 3 + 2])+'\n' )
Outputfile.close()
```

i just post it there if someone need helps.